# Conversion of IEnumerable<T> to IList

Tags: .net, generics, ienumerable, ilist

If a method takes a parameter of type System.Collections.IList can I legitimately/safely pass a value of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`?

I would appreciate a thorough explanation of why this is possible and what actually happens to the object `T` when the `IEnumerable<T>` is used inside of the method.

Is it converted to the base type of Object?

Is it used as an `System.Collections.IEnumerable`?

Are there any scenarios where this will cause problems (i.e. performance issues)?

Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**No**, You cannot pass an `IEnumerable<T>` to a method which takes `IList`. The interface `IEnumerable<T>` is not convertible to `IList` and attempting to pass a variable of type `IEnumerable<T>` to a method taking `IList` will result in a compilation error.

In order to make this work you will need to do one of the following

1. Instead of having an `IEnumerable<T>`, maintain a reference to a type which implements both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IList`. `List<T>` is a good candidate here
2. Convert the `IEnumerable<T>` instance to a new object which is convertible to `IList`.  For example, in 3.5+ you can call the `.ToList()` extension method to create a new `List<T>` over the enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to call `ToList()`.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't, without using the [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method. I think that this shouldn't cause *that* big of a performance problem - if you have an alternative, time them and compare.

You could also use [`new List<T>(myIEnumerable)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) - the documentation says that that function is an `O(n)` operation, but I can't find anything else about `ToList()`. Also, remember that `List<T>` also implements `IList` as well as `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerable does not allow indexed access to the collection, whereas IList does. Thus, IList is more than IEnumerable and you won't be able to get away with it. Of course, some classes implement both interfaces (List<> for example) and those will work fine.

If you need to go from IEnumerable to IList, you may try a cast first, if you get lucky it will work. If not, you'll have to foreach over the IEnumerable collection and build a new IList.

Edit: use ToList() instead of foreaching yourself as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't pass it an IEnumerable. IList implements IEnumerable, so if you pass your method an IList, you can safely use it as an IEnumerable. VS won't compile the following:

```
private static void Test(IList<int> list){ }

Test(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
```

Error returned:

```
Argument '1': cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<int>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code was an attempt of mine to convert from IEnumerable<IEnumerable> to IList<IList>.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> iEnumerableOfIEnumerable = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();
IList<IList<int>> iListOfIList = new List<IList<int>>(
    iEnumerableOfIEnumerable.Select(list => list.ToList()));
```